# Behaviour of lua_pushlightuserdata metatables across different modules in c

Tags: c, api, lua

I have been tinkering with the Lua C API and I have stumbled on something that I can't quite figure out on my own.

Well , I am aware that you cannot have multiple lighuserdata with different metatables , but is it possible to have lightuserdata in different C modules with individual mettables even if the pointer is of the same type?

eg.

Module A : lightuserdata points to integer type + Metatable A
Module B : lightuserdata pointes to integer type + Metatable B

I hope that Module B wont overwrite the metatable on the lightuserdata in Module A.

Anyone know if this will happen?

Answer (score 1):

Lightuserdata cannot have individual metatables: all lightuserdata values have the same metatable, which is initially nil. If you give a metatable to a  lightuserdata value, it will be set to all lightuserdata values.

Having individual metatables is the purpose of ordinary, full userdata. Just use full userdata and don't think twice.

Comment: Ok , so this means that if I load several modules using the C API, if the first module has lightuserdata with a metatable attached , it will have the same metatable as the last module loaded by lua, if this last module also has it's own (single) lightuserdata with an individual metatable attached to it?

Comment: @DeLorean, yes. But I feel that you're complicating something in your design.

Comment: I am rewriting hypercube webserver by Anakata , where I need to pass a request and response lua value back to lua through a lua_pcall C API call , I want to wrap the file descriptor for the connection in the lightuserdata , since the fd is created many times over for many connections. using a table or full userdata is too expensive for this type of execution which happens to be a few seconds. I am afraid the GC will be overloaded, I can already see the performance loss by using tables , please advice on how to do this.

Comment: @DeLorean, perhaps you should post a separate question.